# display yuv420p on android

Tags: android, ffmpeg, yuv

I use ffmpeg to decode flv frame to yuv420p.But I don't know how to display it on android
help me please!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recently published some code we were using for FFMPEG on Android:

https://github.com/churnlabs/android-ffmpeg-sample/blob/master/jni/native.c

That first function, fill_bitmap(), fills an Android bitmap with the contents of an AVFrame buffer.

Not the most efficient way to do it, but it's working code. The Android bitmap is an ARGB_8888 and I just set the alpha to zero. Seemed like the best match for the formats the sws_scale() contexts supported.

Comment: My Android SDK is 2.1.So It cannot include android/bitmap.h,Coudle you tell me how get the buffer filled with image data and can be decode by BitmapFactory? Thank you very much!!

Comment: Sorry, don't know the answer to that one, I'm always on the most recent SDK.

Comment: @mikerowehl: I am trying on you rcode on churnlabs. But it seems no images are shown, except a very narrow line on the most right. I debug into it, finding that, it seems fill_bitmap works fine, I see values under the bitmap data (pixels). But when the program jumps to Java file MainActivity.java, I use bitmap.getPixel and find that values are 0. Don't know why.

Comment: @mikerowehl: I find that it works on an old device with the Android version 2.3.5. But for two Nexus devices, it fails. Maybe it is due to ffmpeg libraries compiled by the old NDK? Thanks for your code.

Comment: @user1914692 sorry, but that's really old code now. I haven't run it lately and don't have a good way to test it out on newer devices. It was compiled with older tools though, if that helps at all.

Comment: @mikerowehl: Thank you. I will use the latest library to have a try.

Answer (score 0):

yuv420p format is not supported on android. you need to convert to one of the formats android supports. find the formats **[here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.Config.html)**. You can use FFMPEG's sws_scale function to convert the format from yuv420p to one of the required formats.

Alternatively you can also look at ffplay.c or [ffmpeg tutorial](http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/ffmpeg.html) for how the conversion is performed.